# Variable Naming Conventions For Maps/Lists in Dynamically-Typed languages

Tags: variables, groovy, language-agnostic, naming-conventions, dynamic-typing

I am getting into Groovy language, which has dynamic typing (as well as optional static typing).  It also has native support for Lists, Maps, and Ranges, so I find myself using lists and maps a lot, especially lists of lists, lists of maps, maps of lists, etc.

In static languages (esp with Generics) you always have an idea of what your type is.  I am fairly new to dynamic languages, and it's getting a bit difficult to keep track of what my variable is supposed to be, so I was wondering if other people use some kind of variable naming conventions to keep these straight.

For example, suppose I have a map of dates as key and integers as values.  Or List of integers, or List of Maps that contain strings as keys and account objects as values.

It seems like creating a clear convention behind variable names will help me keep track of what data type structure I am dealing with without having to look it up.

Any tips?

Comment: It's a pity there's no ability to downvote comments. This seems to be a perfectly acceptable question.

Comment: @David, Comments *can* be flagged for "rude" or "non-constructive".

Comment: Although it is common to use "def", it may be uncomfortable to Java programmers, and there is really no advantage to using "def" over "String" or "Map" except perhaps getting teased by Groovy programmers who care more about "style" than the next guy reading their code.  If you like to know what type your objects are, use the actual type if it might be a question.  This also lets the IDE be more helpful (Ctrl-space completion works a lot better).  As you progress, however, you may feel more comfortable with def at times, so use it when it seems right.  Typically generics work as well.

Answer (score 13):

This is a common beginner's lament.  You could use a naming convention, but odds are you'll drop it before too long and focus on *what* the variable represents (its meaning in relation to the rest of the code) rather than worrying about *how* it's represented (it's "type").

Comment: This is a very old question, I know, but for myself, I'm interested not so much in *how* a variable is represented as being able to determine, at glance, what operations are available on it.  For example, I may not care if something is an Array or List, but I do care whether I can iterate over it.  What about a convention in this case?  E.g. "nameList" vs "names"?

Answer (score 8):

The name of your variable should explain to someone reading the code what it is supposed to be, what it stands for. If you have a map of dates to integers, does it represent, for example (suggested variable names are in brackets):

1. a number of payments due on that date (`paymentsDue`)
2. a number of days between mapped date and some other point in time (`daysPassed`)
3. a number of messages posted on that date on Stack Overflow (`numberOfPostedMessages`)

In languages where variable type is not readily available, you might want to append a prefix of suffix, such as `paymentsDueMap`. I would, however, advise against encoding any additional type information inside a variable name, such as `datesToInts` - that routinely does more harm than good.

Finally, if you have a complex data structure, such as a list of maps between strings and accounts, the best thing would be to encapsulate that into a separate class, and name it according to its intent.

Answer (score 3):

> In static languages (esp with Generics) you always have an idea of what your type is.

After a while of programming in dynamic languages, you learn that using types this way is a crutch.  Two pieces of advice:

1. Use good variable naming.  For instance, if you have a map of dates to ints, you can name it something like BirthdateToTotalLookup.
2. Learn what visual clues to look for.  It may seem obvious, but it took me a while to get in the habit of looking for clues like this:

   ```
   sum += x['10-16-92']
   ```

From the piece of code above, I can tell that x is a map that has a date as a key and returns a number of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

If the names can be kept short, then I tend to name maps something like "nounToNoun".  So using your example of dates mapping to integers, I would name that "dateToCount" (if the integers are counters for something).  That way its obvious that it is a map, and its obvious what is being mapped to what.  The problem is that sometimes it is difficult to keep these sort of names short and readable.  For example, "userToLoginHistory" starts getting a little unwieldy.

For lists I generally use a plural for the variable name.  So "user" would be a single user, and "users" would be a list of users.

To be honest, I am not sure what a good name would be for a list of maps.

Answer (score 2):

One of the benefits of dynamic languages is that even if you're using an object as a Map - it doesn't HAVE to be a map. All it has to do is support whatever messages are sent to it. In Groovy, if I know that a given method expects a map so it can look up things by a String key - I can give it the full map, a stripped-down map, an Expando with a property named the same thing as the key, or any other object that has a property named the same thing as the key. This is because someObject["keyname"] and someObject.keyname are the same thing. (Of course if the code calls someObject.get("keyname") I've got to wire that method up somehow.)

The point is, in a dynamic language like Groovy you think less about TYPES and more about SUPPORTED MESSAGES. If it's conceptually a map, fine - naming it birthdateToTotal would make sense (though I prefer to call it 'totals', because totals[birthdate] looks better than birthdateToTotal[birthdate]) - but if it doesn't have to be specified, don't specify it. You leave yourself flexibility later.

Answer (score 2):

This is something you'll outgrow over time.  Not to say I don't know a 20-year programmer still using Hungarian, but he's coding in a static-typed language, so it's almost understandable.

Consider this.  That variable you're naming might be a HashMap, so what type do you add to the name?  Map?  This is a middle-of-the-road answer.  Why not Collection?  Since that way if you decide to change the WAY the data is stored, you don't have to change the variable name.  Why not HashMap, if you really want to let the reader know what's going on.

As you may suspect, none of these are necessary.  The point of a dynamic language (and even of polymorphism) is that you don't need to know the exact type of the variable being presented, only the data itself is important.  While you might like a hint as to how to interface to that data, you'll soon find you already know in most cases, or can easily put that info in the variable without specifying types: addressesByZipCode, totalByBirthdate, etc.